# Accessing a pointer to a figure from another figure in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to access my struct points. The structs memory are dynamically located. I am getting a segmentation fault that I can't figure out. My struct definitions from my .h file are as follows:

```
struct point{
double x;
double y;
};

struct figure{
char name[128];
int draw;
struct point *points;
};

extern struct figure *figures;
```

In my .c file I have:

```
struct figure *figures;

//initializing 10 figures
figures = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct figure));
//left the obvious NULL checking out for brevity 

//I'm fairly sure this portion works for initializing 10 points for each figure
int i;
for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
figures[i].points = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct point));
//left out NULL checking again
}
```

Unless a problem was detected before this point this is where I am having trouble, actually storing values into points. 
NOTE: index could be any int >= 0, just using a general term for simplicity

```
figures[index].points[index]->x = 10;
figures[index].points[index]->y = 15;
```

Any help with his problem would be fantastic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same index used for both figures and points?

Comment: No there is an unknown amount of figures with an unknown amount of points. We get the data from a file, I left out most of the code. Just used index for a more general case

Comment: figures[index].points[index] is a point, not a point pointer.

Comment: You should add a .size member to the struct to remember how many points are there. There are too many numbers in your code!

Answer (score 1):

`figures[index].points` is an array of structures, which means that indexing it (i.e. `figures[index].points[index]`) gives you a structure. The last two lines should be:

```
figures[index].points[index].x = 10;
figures[index].points[index].y = 15;
```

I'm surprised the compiler wouldn't catch this.

Comment: yeah that's weird...maybe he wasn't using gcc

Comment: Graeme that's what I initially thought as well. When i use the ddd debugger the segmentation fault happens on the first line(.x)

Comment: It caught the two lines that I posted, that was just my attempt at what it is "maybe" supposed to be. Had a TA try and look at it for a bit today and he was playing around with the -> operator.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you are accessing the inner structure incorrectly,I don't see any problem in this code.

**[Online Demo](http://www.ideone.com/vRzaW)** of your code sample that works.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct point{
double x;
double y;
};

struct figure{
char name[128];
int draw;
struct point *points;
};


int main()
{
    struct figure *figures;
    figures = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct figure));

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        figures[i].points = malloc(10 * sizeof(struct point));
        figures[i].draw = i;
    }

    i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("\nfigures[%d].draw = [%d]",i,figures[i].draw); 
        int j;
        for(j = 0;j<10;j++)
        {
            figures[i].points[j].x = i;
            figures[i].points[j].y = j;

            printf("\nfigures[%d].points[%d].x = [%f]",i,j,figures[i].points[j].x);
            printf("\nfigures[%d].points[%d].y = [%f]",i,j,figures[i].points[j].y);
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> figures[0].draw = [0]
>   figures[0].points[0].x = [0.000000]
>   figures[0].points[0].y = [0.000000]
>   figures[0].points[1].x = [0.000000]
>   figures[0].points[1].y = [1.000000]
>   figures[0].points[2].x = [0.000000]
>   ...so on